# Add space between Table <tr> based on Conditions

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc

Am dynamically forming rows and columns in my mvc view from the data i receive from model and sample view looks like below

```
for(...)
{
    <tr>

        if()
        {
        <td>
        ---Dynamic content
        </td>
        elseif()
        {
        <td>
        ---Dynamic content
        </td>
        }
        else()
        {
        <td>
        ---Dynamic content
        //In case of else execution i need to add space for the next formed <tr>
        </td>
        }
        }
    </tr>
}
```

Am forming the table rows based on some specific conditions and everything works perfectly and in the above code i need **add space for `<tr>`** in case of else block `<td`> is formed.

In case else block execution and it goes to form next `<tr`> and i need to some way add a space before the `<tr>` is formed.

Code looks messy with table and loops but want an solution how i can dynamically add space between `<tr>` based on conditions.

Thanks

Comment: How about having </tr> closing tag within each block, but in the third block you close the </tr> tag and reopen another within the same block?  (or am I misunderstanding the question)

Comment: For "space" do you mean literal space (&nbsp;) or a blank row?

Answer (score 0):

How about something like...?

```
else()
{
    <td><!-- use this as a spacer row --></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>
    ---Dynamic content
    //In case of else execution i need to add space for the next formed <tr>
    </td>
}
```

Comment: i want space  between <tr> and not <td>